# Get Checkbox values to controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In the below view i'm trying to get the checked checkbox values to the controller for saving in the database.

```
<div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Addresses) %>
            </div>

             <div class="editor-field">
             <% foreach (var item in Model.Addresses)
                { %>
       <input type="checkbox" 
         id="<%: item.addressID %>"
         name="addressOption"
         value="<%: item.addressID%>"/>
       <label for="optionId"><%: item.address%></label>
       <br />
         <% } %>
               </div>
               <br />
            <div class="editor-label">
                <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile) %>
            </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
AdvanceClient cli = new AdvanceClient();

                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {

                        cli.Mobile = Request.Form["Mobile"];

                        foreach (var item in Request.Form["Addresses"])
                        {
                            //here i need to get the checked checkbox values
                        }
                    }
```

I'm stuck with getting the values of checked checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

You can get all values in comma separated string from :

```
var selectedValues = Request.Form["mySharedName"];
 // This is now a comma separated list of values that was checked
```

for you it will be  : `Request.Form["addressOption"]`

after then using `for` loop you can get all values

Comment: hello. thanks for the solution.now i have saved a comma separated string to the database. can u please tell me how can i check the relevant values in Edit view?

Answer (score 0):

You can store arrays like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="addressOption[0]" id="..." value="..." />
<input type="checkbox" name="addressOption[1]" id="..." value="..." />
<input type="checkbox" name="addressOption[2]" id="..." value="..." />
```

Now you just need to have an array in your model with the same name

```
List<int> addressOption;
```

and it will be populated automaticaly on submit.